# XSS Scripting attack Attack -> Can't call javascript

Tags: javascript, php, security, xss

I'm trying to attack a website for to learn security. I can update the value of a `href` but I don't know what to set it to.

I'm currently setting it to: `?onclick=alert(123);`

Inspect elements shows:

`<a href="?onclick=alert(123);">ATTACK</a>`

when I click the link, the url changes to:

`.../view.php?onclick=alert(123);`

but no alert call is called a window isn't shown, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: `javascript:alert(123)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny when I enter it, the website chops the line to `href="alert(123);"`  and then the URL is `.../alert(123);` which is not found on server

Comment: `<script>alert(1);</script>` ?

Comment: `" onclick="alert(1)`

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you're looking for

```
" onclick="alert(123)
```

which should render as

```
<a href="" onclick="alert(123)">ATTACK</a>
```

*Just guessing.*